# Sudo privilege is not working even after adding to sudo users

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, root, users

I have tried to add my user in the sudouser group. I have used  usermod. Which pretty fine worked. But in sudoers

> ```
> # Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
> # %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
> ```

The line is commented. In such case. Even after adding the user, it doesnt have the sudo previlage. The below is the output

```
root@virtual-machine:/etc# usermod -aG sudo qwertyuiop
root@virtual-machine:/etc# sudo mkdir you
root@virtual-machine:/etc# su qwertyuiop
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

qwertyuiop@virtual-machine:/etc$ sudo mkdir check_check_checck
[sudo] password for qwertyuiop:
qwertyuiop is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
qwertyuiop@virtual-machine:/etc$
```

I am trying to do this in a script. Opening and editing the file is not a better solution. Is there any command line workaround for this

Comment: so why don't you uncomment that line? Did you try to relogin/restart?

Comment: Why is the `%sudo` line commented?

Comment: Not sure about the case. I have tested in 3 vms. One of the VM had this line commented.

Answer (score 0):

as root, use visudo to edit the sudoers file (dont edit manually):

```
  # visudo
```

Then change this line to remove the comment:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
# %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

So it looks like this:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Once done, log out as qwertyuiop, log back in, and you should be able to use sudo